# Forked process isn't calling function in C

Tags: c, unix, fork

C beginner here. The function `send_chars_to_reducers` does not appeared to be getting called inside the forked processes created in `fork_mappers` function.

### C Code

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define ALPHA_OFFSET 97
#define LETTERS 26

const int NUM_OF_MAPPERS = 4;
const int NUM_OF_REDUCERS = 26;

const int PIPE_READ_END = 0;
const int PIPE_WRITE_END = 1;
const int PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;

int mapper_pipes[4][2];
int reducer_pipes[26][2];

void pipe_wrapper(int pipefd[]) {
    int ret = pipe(pipefd);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("Error. Failed when trying to create pipes.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void create_mapper_pipes(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_MAPPERS; i++) {
        pipe_wrapper(mapper_pipes[i]);
    }
}

void create_reducer_pipes(void) {
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i < NUM_OF_REDUCERS; i++) {
        pipe_wrapper(reducer_pipes[i]);
    }
}

// Prints an error msg and exits if one occurs. Else, returns the system call value.
int print_if_err(int syscall_val, const char* syscall_name) {
    if (syscall_val < 0) {
        perror(syscall_name);
        exit(errno);
    } else {
        //No syscall error we can return
        return syscall_val;
    }
}

void send_chars_to_reducers(void) {
    printf("hello from send_chars_to_reducers\n");
}

void fork_mappers(void) {


    /* Constants useful to all children */
    char ibuf[PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE]; // input pipe buffer
    int rlen = 0;

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<NUM_OF_MAPPERS; i++) {
        pid_t mapper_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
        close(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
        if (mapper_pid == 0) {
            rlen = print_if_err(read(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END], ibuf, 1000), "read");
            while(rlen > 0) {    
                send_chars_to_reducers();
                printf("read line from forked_mappers, p%d: %s\n", i, ibuf);
                rlen = print_if_err(read(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END], ibuf, 1000), "read");
            }
            _exit(0);
        }
    }
}

void fork_reducers(void) {
    printf("hello from fork_reducers\n"); 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_REDUCERS; i++) {
        pid_t reducer_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
        if (reducer_pid == 0) {
            while (1 == 1) {

            }       
        }
    }
}

void send_lines_to_mappers(void) {
    int wlen = 0;
    char obuf[PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int ob_size;
    int count = 0;

    char buff[BUFFER_SIZE]; // a buffer for each line of the file
    FILE *input_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    // read the input file line by line
    while(fgets(buff, BUFFER_SIZE, input_file) > 0) {
        printf("read line from send_lin_to_mappers: %s\n", buff);
        ob_size = sizeof buff;
        switch(count) {
            case 0 :
                write(mapper_pipes[0][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                close(mapper_pipes[0][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                break;
            case 1 : 
                write(mapper_pipes[1][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                close(mapper_pipes[1][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                break;
            case 2 :
                write(mapper_pipes[2][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                close(mapper_pipes[2][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                break;
            case 3 : 
                write(mapper_pipes[3][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                close(mapper_pipes[3][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                break;
            default :
                printf("you did something wrong in send_lines_to_mappers loop");
        }
        count++;
    }
    fclose(input_file);
}

int main(void) {
    // Setup the mapper pipes
    create_mapper_pipes();
    create_reducer_pipes();
    fork_reducers();
    fork_mappers();
    send_lines_to_mappers();

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
hello from fork_reducers
read line from send_lin_to_mappers: I like coding in C.

read line from send_lin_to_mappers: I like manually allocating memory, and opening the registers window in Visual Studio to see the values of the eax register and blitting graphics to the screen and all the stuff that Dr. Dobbs wrote about in the 90s.

read line from send_lin_to_mappers: My programming friends seem to believe that understanding this level of programming is good in a hand-wavy, theoretical sense, but when you consider all the web development, Java frameworks, and existing libraries most programmers today rely on, it's hard to really pin down a solid answer to the question "Why learn C?"

read line from send_lin_to_mappers: This is my attempt to answer that question, and I believe it comes down to the basic programming concept of abstraction.
```

Comment: `close(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_WRITE_END]);` That is in the wrong spot. You meant to close it for the child process but that's closing it for both parent and child.

Comment: Hey again @kaylum , the thing is if I put the close immediately after the `if (mapper_pid == 0)` I get the `hello from send_chars_to_reducers` to print but the process doesn't exit.

Comment: Well two wrongs don't make a right :) What you have now is definitely wrong. Leaving obvious wrong code in there because it masks another problem isn't really a winning strategy.  So fix that and explain the error that then occurs. For starters, how do you determine that it does not exit?

Comment: @kaylum I know its not exiting because because the cursor doesnt reset and also because if I run ps I see the four forked children processes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the number of processes which share handles.
Each reducer has the pipes open
Each mapper has the pipes open, so the pipes are never properly closed ( the reducers are in a busy loop.

```
    if (mapper_pid == 0) {
      int j;
      for( j = 0; j < NUM_OF_MAPPERS; j++ ){
        close( mapper_pipes[j][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
        if( j != i ){
           close(mapper_pipes[j][PIPE_READ_END]);
        }
    }
```

I commented out the reducer fork's and then fixed the mapper forks to close all the pipe handles in the child except the one we want to read from.

This started to make the program work.
From [pipe documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), you should close the unused bits of a pipe.  But you have pre-opened all the pipes (probably better localizing them), and have therefore got to close all the unused handles in the sub-processes to have the OS tidy up the resource correctly